# Is log4j not thread safe after all?

Tags: java, logging, thread-safety, log4j

(This is on SLES11, Java 7, Tomcat 6, log4j-1.2.16)

We use log4j to write different things to different logfiles.  I've inherited this code, so for good or bad the general structure is here to stay for the time being.

The logger will create two logfiles: `main.log` and `stats.log`.  A certain stats message is logged to both loggers via separate calls (you'll see below) and a whole bunch of other things is logged to the main log.

So all through our code you'll see things like `Log.logMain(someMessageToLog);`.  In one single place in our code (which is executed by multiple threads) there is the following:

```
String statsMessage = createStatsMessage();
Log.logMain(statsMessage);
Log.logStats(statsMessage);
```

The name of the main logger is `main`, the name of the stats logger is `stats`.  The problem is that sometimes under heavy load we see lines in `main.log` that have the string `stats INFO` in it.  Everything in `main.log` should only have `main INFO` in it because that is the only logger logging to that file, plus we see mixed output in some lines.  This seems like a thread-safety issue, but the log4j docs say log4j is thread-safe.  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
2012-03-21 16:01:34,7742012-03-21 16:01:34,774| | stats main INFO   [INFO  http-8080-18]:  [message redacted]. 
2012-03-21 16:01:36,380| main 2012-03-21 16:01:36,380| INFO   [stats INFO  http-8080-15]: [message redacted]. 
2012-03-21 16:01:37,465| main INFO  2012-03-21 16:01:37,465 [| stats http-8080-1]: [message redacted].
```

Here's the `Log` class (stripped down to only show the loggers in question -- there are actually a bunch of other loggers in it, all set up similarly to these):

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;

import java.io.IOException;

final public class Log
{
    private static final String LOG_IDENTIFIER_MAINLOG = "main";
    private static final String LOG_IDENTIFIER_STATSLOG = "stats";

    private static final String MAIN_FILENAME = "/var/log/app_main.log";
    private static final String STATS_FILENAME = "/var/log/app_stats.log";

    private static final int BACKUP_INDEX = 40;
    private static final String BACKUP_SIZE = "10MB";

    private static final PatternLayout COMMON_LAYOUT =
        new PatternLayout("%d| %c %-6p [%t]: %m.%n");

    private static Logger mainLogger;
    private static Logger statsLogger;

    public static void init() {
        init(MAIN_FILENAME, STATS_FILENAME);
    }

    public static void init(String mainLogFilename,
                            String statsLogFilename) {
        mainLogger = initializeMainLogger(mainLogFilename);
        statsLogger = initializeStatsLogger(statsLogFilename);
    }

    public static void logMain(String message) {
        if (mainLogger != null) {
            mainLogger.info(message);
        }
    }

    public static void logStats(String message) {
        if (statsLogger != null) {
            statsLogger.info(message);
        }
    }

    private static Logger getLogger(String loggerIdentifier) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(loggerIdentifier);
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        return logger;
    }

    private static boolean addFileAppender(Logger logger,
                                           String logFilename,
                                           int    maxBackupIndex,
                                           String maxSize) {
        try {
            RollingFileAppender appender =
                new RollingFileAppender(COMMON_LAYOUT, logFilename);
            appender.setMaxBackupIndex(maxBackupIndex);
            appender.setMaxFileSize(maxSize);
            logger.addAppender(appender);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Logger initializeMainLogger(String filename) {
        Logger logger = getLogger(LOG_IDENTIFIER_MAINLOG);
        addFileAppender(logger, filename, BACKUP_INDEX, BACKUP_SIZE);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        return logger;
    }

    private static Logger initializeStatsLogger(String filename) {
        Logger logger = getLogger(LOG_IDENTIFIER_STATSLOG);
        addFileAppender(logger, filename, BACKUP_INDEX, BACKUP_SIZE);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        return logger;
    }

}
```

---

***Update:***

Here's a little program that (at least for me) will reproduce the problem with the above `Log` class:

```
final public class Stress
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            Log.init();
        }
        else {
            Log.init(args[0], args[1]);
        }

        for (;;) {
            // I know Executors are preferred, but this
            // is a quick & dirty test program
            Thread t = new Thread(new TestLogging());
            t.start();
        }
    }

    private static final class TestLogging implements Runnable
    {
        private static int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String msg = new StringBuilder("Count is: ")
                .append(counter++).toString();

            Log.logMain(msg);
            Log.logStats(msg);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.logMain(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And some sample output in the logs:

```
$ grep stats main.log    
2012-03-23 15:30:35,919| stats 2012-03-23 15:30:35,919| main INFO  INFO   [ [Thread-313037]: Thread-313036]: Count is: 312987.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,929| stats INFO   [Thread-313100]: Count is: 313050.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,937| stats INFO   [Thread-313168]: Count is: 313112.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,945| stats INFO   [Thread-313240]: Count is: 313190.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,946| stats INFO   [Thread-313251]: Count is: 313201.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,949| stats INFO   [2012-03-23 15:30:35,949| main INFO  Thread-313281]: Count is: 313231.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,954| stats INFO   [Thread-313331]: Count is: 313281.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,956| 2012-03-23 15:30:35,956stats | main INFOINFO   [   [Thread-313356]: Count is: 313306.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,9562012-03-23 15:30:35,956| main | INFO  stats  [INFOThread-313359]:   Count is: 313309.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,962| stats INFO  2012-03-23 15:30:35,962| main INFO   [Thread-313388]:  [Count is: 313338.
```

and

```
$ grep main stats.log
2012-03-23 15:30:35,913| 2012-03-23 15:30:35,913| main INFO   [Thread-312998]: Count is: 312948.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,915| main INFO   [Thread-313014]: Count is: 312964.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,919| stats 2012-03-23 15:30:35,919| main INFO  INFO   [ [Thread-313037]: Thread-313036]: Count is: 312987.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,931| main INFO   [Thread-313116]: Count is: 313066.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,947| main INFO   [2012-03-23 15:30:35,947Thread-313264]: | Count is: 313214.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,949| stats INFO   [2012-03-23 15:30:35,949| main INFO  Thread-313281]: Count is: 313231.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,956| 2012-03-23 15:30:35,956stats | main INFOINFO   [   [Thread-313356]: Count is: 313306.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,9562012-03-23 15:30:35,956| main | INFO  stats  [INFOThread-313359]:   Count is: 313309.
2012-03-23 15:30:35,962| stats INFO  2012-03-23 15:30:35,962| main INFO   [Thread-313388]:  [Count is: 313338.
```

For what it's worth, out of a 145516-line `main.log` file, "stats" showed up in it 2452 times.  So it's not uncommon but it's not like it happens all the time, either (and of course this test is pretty extreme).

Comment: It could also be a problem with appenders getting crossed somehow, but it doesn't look likely from what you've shown here.  You could always add `synchronized` to  logMain/logStats to try to rule out threads fighting, but if you're running under heavy load the performance hit could make it unfit for production.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

You're sharing the PatternLayout between the two appenders, which according to the above API link:

*This code is known to have synchronization and other issues which are not present in org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout. EnhancedPatternLayout should be used in preference to PatternLayout. EnhancedPatternLayout is distributed in the log4j extras companion.*

So create a new PatternLayout for each appender

Comment: That's what I get for believing the log4j FAQ and its claims that log4j is thread-safe :)  Thank you!  Once I get the chance to verify this on the actual system in question I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: +1 This object just smells of being not thread-safe.  It's contructed with the pattrn string and can also have its pattern property changed later.  It obviously maintains state :(  It would have been better if the pattern string pointer was passed in on every call.

Comment: Making a new `PatternLayout` for each appender did indeed make the problem go away on the specific system in question.  I'm accepting this answer.  Thanks!